# Including Lua in VS2015 C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lua

I would like to integrate Lua into my current C++ application I build with VisualStudio 2015 (x64 mode).

I grabbed a simple Lua wrapper from [here](https://github.com/eliasdaler/unnamed_lua_binder), and the Lua binaries for windows x64 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.1.5/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/) (the lua-5.1.5_Win32_dll14_lib.zip one).

Next, I added the include and library path to the project preferences. Works so far in the IDE. However, when I try to compile the code it throws 24 errors (like these first two):

```
1>LuaScript.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "lua_close" referenced in function ""public: __cdecl LuaScript::~LuaScript(void)" (??1LuaScript@@QEAA@XZ)".
1>LuaScript.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "lua_gettop" referenced in function ""public: void __cdecl LuaScript::clean(void)" (?clean@LuaScript@@QEAAXXZ)".
```

which tells me next to nothing. Seems that the linker is unable to find the library but the includes are working and the path to library is set, too. Any suggestions what I might have missed or should look into? Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you including lua.hpp or lua.h ? Look at the .hpp file since it wraps everything into extern "C" { } which is required in C++ app, and Lua itself is a C library. Also since lua is actually pretty small and great at embedding is it worth going with a DLL instead of just dropping in the source? Another thing, if you use DLL do you link to the .lib that has symbols? As a side note: Lua has already 5.3 version, these DLL's are 5.1.5, any particular reason to use that old version?

Comment: The class uses the extern "C" block that is also contained in the .hpp file, so this should work. The reason I decided to use the 5.1.5 version is that eventually I want to use the LuaJIT library which unfortunately is not compatible with 5.3 ... open source is a blessing and a curse. I just removed all additional paths and linked against the 5.1 dll which now compiles and works, that was quite a usefull idea! I still don't understand why this works, must have messed up those additional paths

Comment: You should specify `lua.lib` file and path to it in `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` field. Here's a bit complicated example of using Lua: I build it within my project (I don't use Lua binaries) -- https://github.com/slavanap/ssifSource